# rstan: gamma coef, convergence

Tags: r, stan

I want to familiarise myself with rstan and have this simulated example, where I want to force b to be above 0 (coef on x) using a gamma distribution. Despite 5000 iter (2500 after burn) I get R_hat not close to 1 and n_eff quite small. How come this doesn't converge so well? The chart show trimodal coefficients.

```
set.seed(100)
x <- rnorm(100, 10)
y <- 100 + .2*x + rnorm(100)
cor(x,y)
dat <- list(N=100, x=x, y=y)

scode <- "
data {
  int N;
  vector[N] y;
  vector[N] x;
}

parameters {
  real a;
  real b;
  real sig;
  real<lower=0> c;
  real<lower=0> d;
}

model {
  y ~ normal(a + b * x, sig);
  b ~ gamma(c, d);
}
"

fit <- stan(model_code=scode, model_name='test', data=dat, iter=5000, chains=3, verbose=T)
```

Comment: You may want to post this to the Stan users google mailing list.

Comment: you don't constrain b or the normal variance to be positive, so that's at least part of the problem.

Comment: To whom it may concern: I've retracted my close vote because upon futher inspection, it became clear that this model struggles due to numerous identification issues, and these are ultimately statistical problems. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

A couple notes:

1. When a parameter has constrained support, you should declare that in the parameters block. For example, the variance must be positive. When you don't declare that, your sampler will select negative variance, try it, and reject. This wastes time. Fixing that issue alone increased the walltime to run the model immensely, even if it didn't fix the other issues.
2. The model isn't identified when there's no prior on sigma. This is covered in any Bayesian statistics text -- the posterior is improper. Put any proper prior sigma, and this will fix identify that portion of the model.
3. Constraining c and d likewise improves the model. I just bounded them between 0 and 100, but any plausible range will do fine. But really what you need here is a hierarchical model that puts some nonuniform probability on c and d, since even under the uniform model, some movement in one can be offset by movement in another. This is another identification question and is addressed in the stan users guide.

The revised model achieves $\hat{R}<1.1$ in 1500 iterations for all parameters very quickly in terms of wall-time, even if the effective sample size is tiny.

```
library(rstan)
set.seed(100)
x <- rnorm(100, 10)
y <- 100 + .2*x + rnorm(100)
cor(x,y)
dat <- list(N=100, x=x, y=y)

scode <- "
data {
  int N;
  vector[N] y;
  vector[N] x;
}

parameters {
  real a;
  real<lower=0> b;
  real<lower=0> sig;
  real<lower=0, upper=100> c;
  real<lower=0, upper=100> d;
}

model {
  y ~ normal(a + b * x, sig);
  b ~ gamma(c, d);
  sig ~ normal(0,1);
}
"

fit <- stan(model_code=scode, model_name='test', data=dat, iter=1000, chains=3, verbose=F)
fit
plot(fit)
```

Comment: Thank you, re 3 which part of the guide is that?

Comment: (3) is essentially just the observation that you could have two different gamma distributions with the same mean. Moreover, when those distributions occur with equal probability, there's no identification in the model. This *particular* case of gamma distributions isn't covered, but it's the same idea as the "two intercept" model in the section on model identifiability.